# Bot not responding to message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to this and have been following a tutorial online but I cannot figure out why the bot will not respond to the message.

Things I have checked:

- the tokens match up
- bot has proper permissions
- not missing any ";" etc etc

Here is the code for reference

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages] });

const token = <token>;

bot.on('ready' , () =>{
    console.log('ts ready gangy :3');
})

bot.on('message', msg=>{

 if(msg.content === "hi"){

 msg.reply('hi');
   }
})

bot.login(token);
```

---

The code runs and the bot will appear online as normal but when inputting "hi" and sending it, the bot gives no response.

Comment: Just try reply without if to check is bot.on works. Reply with msg.content to check what bot recieve. Its called 'debugging'  just try different variants to figure out whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Add `Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` to your intents and tick [Message Content Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCiXi.png) if you didn't tick